Pydantic Dynamic .env Files
I'm new to pydantic, I want to use it for Settings management in my app, I have a monorepo with some overrides. I wonder what is the "Pydantic" way of initializing the Settings class with a dynamic list of .env files.
My initial thought was to pass it in the ctor, but I've seen few opinions advising against using ctor with Pydantic.
the functionality I want to achieve is something like:
AppSettings that will contain:
UtilsSettings
DataAccessSettings
all of the 3 will be have a dedicated static default values file and I wish to have another file that will be loaded dynamically and can override the defaults.

It's actually quite well documented: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/pydantic_settings/#other-settings-source
You can define multiple Sources, even different sources, however you feel like. Doesn't it suit your needs?

my main issue is with defining the sources dynamically, if they were static then I wouldn't have any issue.

Well, you can override any model config attribute, by providing the field to the constructor with a leading underscore. I.e. something like MyModel(_env_file=[...]) should be possible. Maybe it will even work, if you add that field to the JSON, but I never tried that.

Or do you meant, that you want to load the env-files iteratively at different points in time?

Yes, the first one, eventually I used a custom constructor. looks like it is working well
